# How to query with multiple 'and' conditions in where clause in Strapi, GraphQL?

Tags: angular, graphql, where-clause, apollo, strapi

Now I am trying to query with multiple _and inside where in Strapi GraphQL playground. The query I am using is:

```
 {
  clients(
    where: {
      _and: [{ name: { _contains: "a" } }, { endDate: { _gte: "2017-12-31" } }]
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
    endDate
    reasonForEnding
  }
}
```

But getting an error with says the following:

```
 "Error: Your filters contain a field '_and' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations".
```

How to do properly query with multiple _and conditions where clause in Strapi with GraphQL

Comment: I found the answers so it is different from performing "_or" with where clause. So it can be done as follows: where: {name_contains: "", endDate_gt : "1900-12-12"}, no need for _and operator.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering your own question, I managed to solve it your way, however it doesn't work when one of the condition is to check for NULL in field, let's say `{name_null: true}`

Answer (score 2):

```
clients(
  where: {
    and: [{ name: { contains: "a" } }, { endDate: { gte: "2017-12-31" } }]
  }
) {
    id
    name
    endDate
    reasonForEnding
  }
```

This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to @Mohammad Sadeq Sirjani's answer; instead of `and`, it is `_and`. So in summary it would be:

```
clients(
  where: {
    _and: [{ name: { contains: "a" } }, 
           { endDate: { gte: "2017-12-31" } }]
         }
) {
    id
    name
    endDate
    reasonForEnding
  }
```